# Should I ask a new question to get an answer to one part of another question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

So I was busy typing up a question asking when Aizen switched with Momo in *Bleach*. As I was typing, I saw the question [Aizen vs Everyone](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/12987/1587) which asked more or less the same thing, but asking when Aizen activated Kyoka Suigetsu and switched with Momo.

The answer that the question received answered the first part which I already knew, but it didn't actually answer the second part which was what I was about to ask.

Would it be better if I asked my question on just the switching of Momo? Or would I be better served requesting a more complete answer?

Comment: sure, that's a different specific question

Answer (score 5):

If it's a question that elaborates on the existing one, asking a new one might be a better idea than editing an already answered post.

I'd recommend mentioning the other post directly, and why its answers don't address your specific question. That way, you show that you are aware of the other post, and it's not a duplicate, but rather a new question. Doing this also leaves a breadcrumb to the original question, which means they'll both show up on the sidebar for each other, and are more easily findable.